# Use Dagger2 in android library project throws `NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime

Tags: java, android, gradle, noclassdeffounderror, dagger-2

I'm using dagger2 in one of my android library. After finish the library project, I use `gradle uploadArchive` to upload an aar to a maven repo. then use the `compile group:artifect:version@aar` syntax in an app project to consume the library project. I have no problem building the app, but at runtime, it throws `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class `MyModule_ProvideAppFactory` generated my Dagger2. I figure this class is generated for the method `@Provides public Application provideApp()`. Yet the generated `DaggerMyComponent` can be found at runtime, since the exception happens inside `DaggerMyComponent` class. 
I even included the following dependencies in the app project

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Yet the problem still existed. I'm pretty sure not because of the `65K method limits` problem because we have enabled multidex in the app project. I'm not sure what I've been missing, or can Dagger2 be used this way?

Comment: It might have something to do with the multidex, although I'm not sure why.... are you certain that you aren't just bundling the entire Google Play Services instead of its modules, or that you can't use Proguard to prune your stuff?

Comment: Chris.Zou I'm facing the same issue - did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: @Eladb See the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2):

Turned out I was missing another dependency which are required by the classes generated by Dagger2.
Add

`compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'`

to the gradle file and it works fine.